# Lagranges multiplier to minimize function of two variables with two constraints

Tags: economics, lagrange-multiplier

I have a Cobb Douglas type production function with $K$ and $L$ as inputs; $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$ as output elasticities and $C$ as efficiency parameter. Now I have to minimize cost $=wL+rK$ w.r.t two constraints

1. Cobb Douglas output constraint and
2. $L=1$.

Please help me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What does the Cobb-Douglas function look like, can you write it down explicitly or at least give some defining properties?

Comment: Sorry i'm new here and i do not know how to write equations here.My Cobb Douglas production function is like  1=CL^\alpha K^(1-\alpha).

Comment: $$1=CL^\alpha K^(1-\alpha) $$

Comment: You mean like $1 = CL^\alpha K^{1- \alpha}$?

Comment: To write $K^{1 - \alpha}$, put braces, "{}", around "1 - \alpha"!

Comment: You are more than welcome.  It should look like this:  "K^{1 - \alpha}"; then surround the whose thing with dollar signs and you should get $K^{1 - \alpha}$

Answer (score 0):

You have to minimize:

$\mathcal L(K|L=1)= w\cdot 1+rK+ \lambda \left(\overline Y - C \cdot K^{\alpha} \cdot 1^{1-\alpha}  \right )=w+rK+ \lambda \left(\overline Y - C \cdot K^{\alpha}   \right )$

$\overline Y$ is the given output (output constraint).

Now calulate $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial K}=0,\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=0$ Then solve this two equations for $K^*$.

Comment: Sir, I did like you told... but the issue here is the equation $$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial K}=0 $$ is not playing any role in calculating value of K*. I am getting  value of K* from $$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=0 $$ equation only..please tell me whether i'm making some mistake.

Comment: @MAthEco I think you are right. The constraint determines $K^*$. Thus the cost are also determined. Then the costs cant be minimized, if $r, \alpha, w, L, Y$ and $C$ are given.

Comment: @MAthEco You only can express $K^*$ by $ r,C$ and $\alpha$, if you use $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial K}=0$

Comment: yes it will give me K^* in terms of r,C and $$\alpha$$But using $$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial K}=0 $$ will give me only value of $$\lambda $$ in terms of r,C and $$\alpha$$.